# Some Java Modulo / Remainder operator questions

Tags: java, modulo

I've been playing with some bigger values with Java, and I'm running across something I don't understand. For some reason, Java seems to like giving me bum data (although, it's far more likely I'm telling it to give me bum data)

Here's a snippet, edited for clarity:

```
        System.out.println(
                "2 == " + (Math.pow(51, 13) % (77))
        );
```

Which, according to both Wolfram Alpha (See link below), and the rest of my algorithm is wrong.

(Output:)

```
  2 == 70.0
```

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=51^13+mod+77](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=51%5E13%20mod%2077)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's because of a precision issue. `double`s are only precise up to 15 or so digits. `Math.pow(51,13)` is a huge number (~20 digits) so when you try modding it by 77, you're going to have numerical errors.

For arbitrary precision arithmetic, take a look at [BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: I thought so too, but double has a MAX_VALUE of (2-2^52)·2^1023, which I think is greater then my number. Thoughts?

Comment: It's not a range issue, it's a precision issue. So for example, instead if storing the number 0.12345678987654321, a `double` might truncate it to just 0.123456789. Likewise for large numbers, 12345678987654321 might be truncated to 12345678900000000. Clearly this messes up the accuracy of the subsequent mod.

Comment: That sounds totally sane. Thank you!